# How to simplify my build process using Docker

Tags: linux, docker

For one of my projects, I currently utilizing the following build process:

- I'm using acbuild to fetch a clean docker image, download all the dependencies as source, and build all my dependencies from source inside the image.
- After all the dependencies are present, I build my project from source inside the image. (using chroot)

Issues with that:

- Building all the dependencies takes an awful lot of time.
- I keep the URL to fetch for the dependencies in a separate config file.

Since URLs break and go down all the time, it causes a great deal of frustration.

Do you have any suggestion on how to improve on this build process? Preferably using just Docker?

Comment: Your question is so broad, I have no idea where to start. I'd probably say , start with reading Docker introduction, then docs.

Comment: Why don't you split the dependencies into a separate build. Then your own build process can start with everything from that build so should be done less often (only when deps changed instead of every time). Also, there is no magical solution to URLs breaking, unless you can switch to standard repositories or a package manager for your dependencies.

I've no idea what the `chroot` is for.

Answer (score 2):

First, use a repository manager like Artifactory or Nexus to cache your dependencies locally. (Artifactory supports Maven, Ivy, Gradle and Docker repositories). That should speed up your builds and also fix the problem of URLs breaking.

If it's still not fast enough, build a separate Docker base image that includes your dependencies preinstalled/precached, and use `FROM` in your `Dockerfile` to build on top of that base image.